# Is there any numerical solver in python with control of each iteration?

Tags: python, linear-algebra

I am solving a linear system of equation currently i am using

```
   numpy.linalg.solve
```

It returns the solution of the linear system.
   I want to have a control such that i can execute iterations

Considering another option

```
    scipy.optimize.minimize
```

Documentation describes that we can specify a function which is called 
   after every iteration and we could have current parameters.
   I am not sure if they meant that we could get the current resultant vector.
   e.g Simply I want to access x after every iteration, while we are solving Ax=b

I am wondering if somebody has worked with it and can explain!

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by the "resultant vector"? The function gets the parameters, i.e. initially `x0`, and must return their cost/objective value.

Comment: we are solving Ax=b, I mean to get access to x after every iteration, which i call the resultant vector

Comment: I have updated the question as well, +1 for mentioning it

Answer (score 2):

The `callback` keyword argument to `scipy.optimize.minimize` specifies a function that will be called with the current estimate of the argument that minimizes the function at each iteration.

But `minimize` is intended for a scalar function (one returning a single value) so I don't see how that is applicable to your example.  You may want to try `scipy.optimize.fsolve` instead.  It doesn't accept the `callback` keyword though.  To get around that, you could wrap your linear equation in a callable function object (that returns `Ax-b`) and then just take the argument that is passed to your callable object.

```
class Ab:
    def __init__(self, A, b):
        self.A = A
        self.b = b
    def __call__(self, x):
        print 'x =', x
        return A.dot(x) - b
```

Then use it like this:

```
>>> A = np.array([[2, 3], [4, 9]], float)
>>> b = np.array([5, 5])
>>> f = Ab(A, b)
>>> optimize.fsolve(f, [0, 0])
x = [0 0]
x = [ 0.  0.]
x = [ 0.  0.]
x = [  1.49011612e-08   0.00000000e+00]
x = [  0.00000000e+00   1.49011612e-08]
x = [ 5.         -1.66666667]
x = [ 5.         -1.66666667]
array([ 5.        , -1.66666667])
```

`fsolve` reported only taking 5 iterations so it appears the first two calls may be not actually used for convergence.

Comment: But surely, `minimize` can be used to find a least-squares solution of Ax=b (though probably slower than a dedicated solver)?

Comment: Yes, I guess you could just write a function that returns the sum of squared values of `Ax-b` and pass that to `minimize`.